# Firemonkey TEdit Uppercase

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6

I am having problem with Firemonkey TEdit Uppercase in Android.

Code:

```
procedure TFormMain.Edit1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
    KeyChar := UpCase(KeyChar);
end;
```

In Win32 it works but in Android it's not working.

Comment: We don't know where this code is, in what context it runs.

Comment: I added it in Edit1KeyDown

Comment: Please edit the Q to include the code

Answer (score 3):

You have to use ChangeTracking event. It works fine

**This code works on Android**

```
procedure TFormMain.Edit1Typing(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text:=AnsiUpperCase(Edit1.Text);
  Edit1.GoToTextEnd;
end;
```

**This code works on windows**:

```
procedure TFormMain.Edit1ChangeTracking(Sender: TObject);
var
  thetext: String;
begin
  thetext := Edit1.Text;
  Edit1.OnChangeTracking := nil;
  Edit1.Text := '';
  Edit1.Text := AnsiUpperCase(thetext);
  Edit1.OnChangeTracking := Edit1ChangeTracking;
  Edit1.GoToTextEnd;
end;
```

Comment: I'm sorry.. I made a mistake. Unfortunately it works only on windows platform.
Let me investigate better.

Comment: Ok I've found the solution. Take a look to my edited code above

Comment: The solution for Android (above) works in Delphi 10.1 Berlin on Android and Windows, without needing to use GoToTextEnd

Answer (score 0):

Use ToUpper ([Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Character.TCharHelper.ToUpper)) or AnsiUpperCase ([Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.AnsiStrings.AnsiUpperCase)) for strings.

UPDATE: Why are you using OnKeyDown? According to [Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Edit.TCustomEdit.OnChangeTracking) you must use OnChangeTracking: "This event provides the first opportunity to respond to modifications the user brought to the text of the edit control."

So put in OnChangeTracking something like

```
procedure TFormMain.Edit1ChangeTracking(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.text:= AnsiUpperCase(Edit1.text);
end;
```

Comment: `UpCase` works fine. You need to diagnose and understand the problem before deciding on the solution.

Comment: I wanted to Auto-CAPS all entered Alphabet on TEdit. Anyway, is there a method for Keyboard Type to set all CAPS?

Comment: @edmund We understand what you want to do but you haven't given us enough information yet to understand why your code does not perform as you hope.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry, When user input on Edit1 make it all CAPS.

Comment: @LHristov It doesn't work on Android but in Win32 it's working.